# Remove the outline and shadow of my buttons, outline=0 in css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```css
.btn btn-default dropdown-toggle {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}
#dropdownMenu1 {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-2" style=" height: 150px;">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" style="margin-top: 100px;background-color: #F5F5DC ">
      <b>Company</b>
      <span class="caret"> </span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li><a href="#"><b>About Us</b></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>Vision</b></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><b>Mission</b></a>
      </li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I tried using outline=0 and shadow=none in my external css file but still it isn't working. I want it to show just the menu names with the arrow sign which will open the dropdown menu.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also instead of answering, please comment or edit your question.

Comment: To be able to help you we need a minimal runnable code example, a description of what you want and what you have tried and how it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably `border` that you need to set to none. Hard to say without seeing any code.

---

EDIT: your css selector is wrong.

```
.btn btn-default dropdown-toggle
```

means "select all elements with tag-name `dropdown-toggle` somewhere inside an element with tag name `btn-default` somwehere inside an element with class `btn`".

Depending on how wide you want your rule to apply, you would select all default buttons using `.btn-default` or only the toggles using `.dropdown-toggle`. If you are resistant to learning the basics of CSS, just copy'paste the following:

```
.dropdown-toggle {
  border: none !important;
}
```

Your ID-selector is correct, by the way, but you have no element with that ID.

Comment: I am trying to upload the code but I am not being able to upload

Comment: You are not supposed to upload any code, you extract the relevant parts and copy'paste it into the question, marked as code.

Comment: <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" style="margin-top: 100px;background-color: #F5F5DC ">
    <b>How it works</b>
    <span class="caret"> </span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#"><b>Our Science</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Your Privacy</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><b>Research Participation</b></a></li>    
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    
  </ul>
</div>

Comment: I copied only the dropdown button portion of the code

Comment: Read my comment again, then remove your comments above and paste the code **into the question** marked **as code**

Comment: On clicking the button a lightblue border is appearing. Is it possible to remove that also?

Comment: @SayantanMitra Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Can you tell me how to remove that?

Comment: I probably can, but I am not willing to help anyone too lazy to try themselves. It's rude and disrespectful to ask other people for help without trying yourself first. Please consider learning HTML, CSS and bootstrap. Then google for your problem. If you can't find a solution after that, create a new question on Stack Overflow, describe your problem in detail and show us what ways you have tried that didn't work.